# Is it possible to sort an array in jQuery?

Tags: arrays, jquery

I'm after parsing a .csv file and turning it into a jQuery array!  Now I want to sort the list so that I can read its values in order of ID number (a value within the array).
Here is my array:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "path/to/file.csv",
    success: function(data) {
        var array1 = data.split("\n");
        var array2 = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            array2.push(array1[i].split(","));
            ...
        }
```

array is in this format:

```
[0] = ID, TITLE, NUMBER
[1] = 1, Name1, 0        << ie: [1][0], [1][1], [1][2]
[2] = 2, Name2, 14
[3] = 3, Name3, 25
[4] = 4, Name4, 66
[5] = 5, Name5, 87
[6] =
```

In order to ignore the first (title) row and the last (empty) row, I use:

```
if($.isNumeric(array2[i][0])){
    //do something
}
else {
    //do nothing
}
```

The rest if the data gets used as required.  However, sometimes the files are not in order.  I would like to select the row that has ID '1' first, ID '2' next and so on...

```
[0] = ID, TITLE, NUMBER
[1] = 5, Name5, 87        << ie: [1][0], [1][1], [1][2]
[2] = 2, Name2, 14
[3] = 4, Name4, 66
[4] = 3, Name3, 25
[5] = 1, Name1, 0
[6] =
```

Is there a way I can sort the array list? Or would I need to read the data to see whats there each time? (i.e. iterate through the list to find out what row my next ID is on)

Comment: Not with jQuery, but you could use the native array sort method, its purpose is... sorting arrays...

Comment: [array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) -- one of the examples there should set you on the right track.

Comment: Why push the header row and the empty row onto array2?  Wouldn't it be better to change your success function to filter those out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has the sort function

```
var myArray = [ 3, 4, 6, 1 ];

myArray.sort(); // 1, 3, 4, 6
```

You can see here for more examples

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/arrays/

but i can't tell you if it works in the array with the format you posted. This should just be a tip, not a solution

Comment: *"**JavaScript** has the sort function"*

Comment: This worked... After declaring var array1 = data.split("\n");, I can call array1.sort(); and then continue with the code as normal.  Nice!  Also, I voted you up because .sort() is a lot easier than .sort(a,b)....

Comment: @PatrickKeane - Not to be nit picky, but there is no `.sort(a,b)`.  There is only `.sort(comparingFunction)`, where the `comparingFunction` can be omitted IF you are sorting a one-dimensional array of integers.  So this answer might just coincidentally work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the built-in sort function? You can provide a custom comparator.

```
    var array = [[30, 'test'], [2, 'okay'], [4, 'yeah']];
    array.sort(function(a,b) {return a[0] - b[0]});
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom sort, as such...

```
array2.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[2] - b[2];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.sort`  function

```
array1.sort(function(a,b){
    return a[0] - b[0];
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6aNUc/)